# key down command doesn't work with regular keys

Tags: applescript, key

Let's say that I want to press the "c" key for 5 seconds and then release it. That's what I'm trying to do:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down "c"
    delay 5
    key up "c"
end tell
```

But it just doesn't work. It always presses "a" regardless to the letter. I even tried with the key code 8 (equivalent for c) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: That's the normal behavior. `key up / down` works only with the modifier keys ⌃⇧⌥⌘.

Comment: How can I do it with regular keys? I need to keep a key pressed.

Comment: Not with vanilla AppleScript. Maybe with AppleScriptObjC

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command `keystroke`. So the code would look something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set fiveSecondsFromNow to (time of (current date)) + 5
    repeat until (time of (current date)) is fiveSecondsFromNow
        keystroke "c"
    end repeat
end tell
```